# R Time Series Issues

Tags: r, time-series

I would like to know more details about R issues mentioned in [Time Series Analysis and Its Applications: With R Examples](http://www.stat.pitt.edu/stoffer/tsa3/Rissues.htm).

For e.g. the first problem still exists in R version 3.0.1

```
# generate an AR(1) with mean 50
set.seed(66)      # so you can reproduce these results
x = arima.sim(list(order=c(1,0,0), ar=.9), n=100) + 50   
mean(x)  
  [1] 50.60668   # the sample mean is close
arima(x, order = c(1, 0, 0))  
  Coefficients:
           ar1  intercept  <--  here's the problem
        0.8971    50.6304  <--  or here, one of these has to change
  s.e.  0.0409     0.8365
```

*direct copy from the webpage

Theoretical model of above simulation is:
$X_t = 5 + 0.9 X_{t-1} + Z_t$, where $\{ Z_t\} $ is the white noise

Is R following particular model convention or is R wrong?  If it is wrong, it is still in R core package and I wonder why it isn't changed.

Also, it would be very helpful if I get some hint on other five issues.

Comment: Is it your contention that the estimate of the intercept parameter must equal the sample mean? (You should be explicit what you think should happen and why you think it.)

Comment: @Glen_b, I like to see the correct estimate of intercept to be populated in the output. I would like to know: is it a typo error of R output? if yes, why it is not fixed?

Comment: @Kalman: the issue is explained perfectly clearly on the page you linked to. This sounds like a bug request to R, which isn't really appropriate here. Perhaps you should submit a request to the R maintainers?

Comment: Thanks @naught101. But, this is an old issue and it is from R core package. I just posted here to make sure it is a bug. My next step would be to submit a request o the R maintainers.

Comment: @Kalman I've come across other issues. One is with regard to the calculation of residuals using `arima()`.  For example, estimating an arima(1,0,0) model while specifying `method = c("CSS")` results in the first residual being calculated as precisely equal to zero. On the other hand, specifying `method = c("CSS-ML")` and `method = c("ML")` will give you a non-zero first residual. The problem here is that with an AR(1) model with, say, a sample size of 60, the first residual should be NA. That is, there ought to be 59 residuals. R will give you 60 and it does something funny with the first one.

Comment: Thanks Graeme. I guess R is not perfect for time series.

Comment: sas also has the same problem

Comment: Thanks @IrishStat. I thought SAS is perfect (error free) tool for any statistical analysis. Is all listed problem in the webpage also with SAS?

Comment: @Kalman, any updates? did you send mail to R maintainers?

Answer (score 3):

In a case like this, first read the help page *carefully*. It might be that the implementation in R uses conventions and parametrizations that differ from what you expect. The `arima` help page clearly states in the Details section that the ARMA representation used applies to `X - m` if `include.mean = TRUE`, which is the default for ARMA models. The documentation of the `include.mean` argument says:

*Should the ARMA model include a mean/intercept term?*

Hence, from the coefficients output and reading the help page, the `intercept` parameter is `m`.

Surely, the casual user might expect that the intercept is something else, because he or she is using a different parametrization. This can be inconvenient, and if the conventions used by R differ from what most users expect, it can even be considered a design flaw. But it is not a bug! The implementation computes what is intended and documented.

But why not just change the name of the parameter in the output to "mean"? Doing so might break other peoples code that rely on the parameter names, as well as break code internally in the stats package. Making a design change is really difficult, and even if many find it inconvenient that the parameter is called "intercept" and not "mean", you should not expect that this will ever be changed in R.

And please don't put more faith into SAS than it deserves.

Comment: Thanks @NRH. It is a very good explanation. I would wait for two or three days any other reply.

Comment: Adding this explanation in the help may be the best way to avoid the confusion.