# Estimation of AR($p$) model by `lm` versus `arima` in R: different results

Tags: r, regression, time-series, arima, linear-model

I'm in the middle of reading a book [Forecasting: Principles and Practice](http://otexts.org/fpp2/) and simultaneously trying to code "by hand" all the things, for better understanding.

I've found something that I cannot explain:

1. Given a time-series generated by AR(2) process,
2. I try to model it as linear regression problem
3. Judging from what I've read so far- it should be perfectly possible to find matching coefficients using both methods.

Unfortunately, I get different results. Question is why?

AR(p) model is described by the equation:

$$
y_t = \epsilon_t + \phi_1y_{t-1} + \phi_2y_{t-2} + ... + \phi_py_{t-p}
$$

I've lagged time-series by 1 and 2 and created classical dataframe with three columns:

- current x
- t-1 x
- t-2 x
  and performed regression.

R code example below:

```
library(xts)
x <- arima.sim(model = list(order=c(2,0,0), ar=c(0.6,0.3)), n=100)
x.ts <- as.xts(x)

# Generate dataframe
x.lag1 <- lag(x.ts, 1)
x.lag2 <- lag(x.ts, 2)
x.df <- data.frame(
  x.curr=x.ts[-c(1:2)],
  x.lag1=x.lag1[-c(1:2)],
  x.lag2=x.lag2[-c(1:2)]

)

# Fit regression
fit.x <- lm(x.curr ~ ., data=x.df)
summary(fit.x)

# Fit ARIMA
arima(x = x.ts, order = c(2,0,0), include.mean = FALSE)
```

Results are quite different:

```
 #Regression results
 Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
 (Intercept)  0.08173    0.11102   0.736    0.463    
 x.lag1       0.54860    0.10082   5.441 4.11e-07 ***
 x.lag2       0.15724    0.09883   1.591    0.115    

# Arima results
      ar1     ar2        intercept
      0.5919  0.1645     0.5572
s.e.  0.0983  0.1009     0.4268
```

Coefficients are similar, although slightly different. Questions:

- why is it so? Is it this random error component included in every
  observation in AR(p) process?
- how could I model ARMA process with
  differencing (non-stationary) using regression? Should I fit
  regression model to differenced-and-lagged time series just like
  that?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are a few reasons. For one, your ARMA model doesn't include a mean/intercept. For another, the ARMA by default uses sum of squares only to find starting points for an iterative maximum likelihood scheme. Least squares regression (which throws away early data points), is usually called conditional sum of squares (CSS) in time series.

These should match up

```
summary(lm(x.curr ~ ., data=x.df))
arima(x = x.ts, order = c(2,0,0), include.mean = T, method="CSS") # note the mean and method arguments
```

Well you'll notice that there's a difference between `lm`'s intercept and the `arima`'s mean. The relationship is that the intercept equals the mean times $(1 - \phi_1 - \phi_2)$. You can verify that this works.

Also, and this makes everything much more confusing, the `arima` function will call its mean the intercept. This is a well-known issue covered in other questions such as [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/60803/r-time-series-issues) one, and is also explained [here](http://www.stat.pitt.edu/stoffer/tsa2/Rissues.htm).

One more thing: your description for an AR(p) model is only true if you're looking at mean zero AR models. In general you can write it as
$$
(1 - \phi_1B - \cdots - \phi_p B^p)(X_t - \mu) = \epsilon_t
$$
where $\mu$ is the mean, or 
$$
(1 - \phi_1B - \cdots - \phi_p B^p)X_t = c + \epsilon_t
$$
where $c$ is the intercept. This will help you with the intercept/mean dilemma above.

Finally, regarding your last question:

> how could I model ARMA process with differencing (non-stationary)
>   using regression? Should I fit regression model to
>   differenced-and-lagged time series just like that?

You can either difference your nonstationary series, perhaps with `diff` in R, or by changing the `order` argument in your call to `arima`. For example, fitting an AR(3) to differenced data, is the same as an ARIMA(3,1,0), and so would require the parameter `c(3,1,0)`.

Comment: Hi! 
Thanks a lot for help. I was pretty sure that ARMa underneath is a normal regression model. Your answer and explanation clarifies almost everything I need, except the second question :)
I know how to do this in R or Python using built-in tools :) I was rather asking how I can replicate this process by myself using regression. So, for example, to fit ARIMA(3,1,0) process should I perform regression with three independent (lagged) x variables? What about diff in this case? I'm just curious - of course normally I use ARIMA.

Comment: @Animattronic you can see that there are a lot of things going on in this question. It might be best to continue this on a separate thread. But yes, an ARIMA(3,1,0) can be written as a regression model. You can use your code above but you need to difference the data first because this has a $1$ in the "I" spot. All the variables, dependent and independent, will be comprised of differenced time series data. The number in the "I" spot is the number of times you have to difference the data. "I" stands for integrated; differencing an integrated process makes it stationary.

Comment: hyndman explains the whole confusing deal very clearly: https://otexts.com/fpp2/arima-r.html