# Difference in coefficients between ar() and lm() using R?

Tags: regression, r, autoregressive, lm

When I use `ar(method="ols")` it should return the same as `lm()`, right? It doesn't:

```
# AR
set.seed(12345)
n <- 100
y <- as.numeric(arima.sim(list(ar = 0.6), n = n))
model_ar <- ar(y, method = "ols", order.max = 1, demean = TRUE, aic = FALSE)
model_lm <- lm(y[2:n] ~ y[1:(n - 1)])

c(model_ar$x.intercept, model_ar$ar) # view coefs ar
model_lm$coefficients # view coefs lm()
```

Results: the slope is the same, the intercept is not. Why? How can I replicate the `ar()` results manually?

```
# Results:
# r$> c(model_ar$x.intercept, model_ar$ar) # view coefs ar
# [1] -0.009013242  0.532853591

# r$> model_lm$coefficients # view coefs lm()
#  (Intercept) y[1:(n - 1)] 
#    0.2478445    0.5328536
```

(Similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37281060/ar-function-vs-lag-variables-in-lm) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/311177/estimation-of-arp-model-by-lm-versus-arima-in-r-different-results) but they're not the same. They ask about `arima()` not `ar()`, or the question is about coef significance, not estimation.)

Comment: I don't know anything about `ar`, but I do see there is an argument `demean`. Does this subtract off the means, which would change the intercept?

Comment: This includes the intercept. Without it, the `$x.intercept` argument would be `NULL` and the coefficients would be the same for `ar(..., method = "ols", demean = F)` and `lm(...-1)`

Comment: Looks like you get the same coefficients if you call `ar(..., method = "ols", demean = FALSE, intercept = TRUE)` -- the default value for `intercept` takes the one of `demean`.

Comment: Look at the help page of `ar.ols`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you checked the **Details** section of the [R documentation of `ar`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/ar), you will find that the model specification used by `ar` is (tailored by your case $p = 1$)
\begin{align*}
x_t - \mu = a_1(x_{t - 1} - \mu). 
\end{align*}
Be mindful though, this specification doesn't include an intercept (this is something weird, because `intercept = TRUE` seems to be the default setting when `ar` is called while the documentation omitted the intercept).  So be more accurate, when use `ar`, you are fitting data to the model
\begin{align*}
x_t - \mu = a_0 + a_1(x_{t - 1} - \mu), \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{align*}
whereas `lm` uses the model specification
\begin{align*}
x_t = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_{t - 1}. \tag{2}\label{2}
\end{align*}
By comparing $\eqref{1}$ and $\eqref{2}$, the correct relation between `ar` and `lm` coefficients should be
\begin{align*}
& a_1 = \beta_1, \\
& \beta_0 = a_0 + \mu(1 - a_1). \tag{3}\label{3}
\end{align*}
That's why you saw the same slope estimates but different intercept estimates. To reconcile two outputs, you would need to manually calculate the sample mean first:

```r
mu <- mean(y) # gives 0.5498442
```

It then follows by $\eqref{3}$ that `-0.009013242 + 0.5498442 * (1 - 0.532853591) = 0.247845`, matches the `lm` intercept output `0.2478445`. Please also check PBull's comment to see how to replicate `lm` output from a direct `ar` call.

Now it should also be clear how to answer your question "How can I replicate the ar() results manually?":

```r
y_centered <- y[2:n] - mu
x_centered <- y[1:(n - 1)] - mu
model_lm1 <- lm(y_centered ~ x_centered)
coef(model_lm1)
```